# MySQL Inserting NULL Value into INT Column

Tags: php, mysql

I know that this question has been asked before. I found the post, however, it did not solve my problem as my column does allow null.

I want to insert a NULL value into my integer column.

```
if ($startYear == "") {
    $startYear = NULL;
}

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Application (startYear) VALUES ('".$startYear."')");
```

Before you ask, I have checked if `$startYear` is ever empty, and it is, so this should work.

When I run this query it inputs a `0` into the database row. It does not insert `NULL` like I want.

Here is my column's structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU7zd.png

One important thing is that, **I can not modify the column's structure. It is off limits.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're not actually inserting into the query the string 'NULL', but a php `null`, which makes your query  insert empty string, this gets coverted to 0 in the DB.

You'd need to do this:

```
  mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Application (startYear) VALUES (NULL)");
```

Comment: @Nic Did this answer your issue correctly? If so, please mark it correct.  If not, was there a better answer?

Answer (score 0):

you're inserting a PHP null value, which when used in a string context becomes an empty string - which is what was originally. You have to insert a literal string with the letters `n`, `u,`l`,`l` for this to work:

```
if ($startYear == '') {
   $startYear = 'NULL'; // string null
}
$sql = "INSERT ..... VALUES ($startYear)";
```

which would produce

```
INSERT ... VALUES (NULL)
```

To expand:

```
   $foo = null; // actual PHP null value
   $bar = "$foo"; // insert this php null into a string
   echo strlen($bar); // returns 0

   $foo = 'null' // string with 4 letters: n,u,l,l
   $bar = "$foo";
   echo strlen($bar); // returns 4
```